# Android AlarmManager Timing Specifics?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here is briefly what I'm running:

**Main.java:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
//make calls any time between 09:30:00 and 09:31:59
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
//we make these random so not all calls are made by all accounts all at once
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, randInt(30, 31));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, randInt(0, 59));

Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Receiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, receiverIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**From what I understand, the above code will:**

- allow the app to run in the background (even if the device is asleep, per `RTC_WAKEUP`)
- does not repeat
- will fire between 09:30:00 and 09:31:59 (`randInt(int, int)` is a custom method) according to New York's time, regardless of where device is located

According to [Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), I can use `setInexactRepeating` or `setRepeating` if I want this alarm to call again automatically. My question beyond this is:

If the first time I open the app is Monday at midnight, the alarm will be set (e.g., for Monday 09:31:20). Let's say I've set the alarm to repeat every 24 hours, then the following (i.e., 2nd) alarm will be set for Tuesday (also at 09:31:20).

*However, what happens when, between Monday's midnight and Tuesday's 09:31:20, I open the app again? The app would call `Main.java` again, which would run the above code again. Would that reset the alarm? Or would they double up?*

*If the 2nd time I open the app the alarm is set for 09:30:55, then would the 2nd alarm override the 1st? Or would there be 2 alarms going off as previously scheduled, one after another?*

I couldn't find anything written on this topic. If anyone knows, please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want it repeating or not? Either way, use `SharedPreferences` to store a `boolean` to indicate whether or not the alarm has been set. If it hasn't then set it otherwise skip that code and do nothing.

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for the `set()` method states: "If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by [`filterEquals(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent))), then it will be removed and replaced by this one.".

Comment: Thank you. These comments are very helpful. Please rewrite as a complete answer if you would like me to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation of the various set methods, `AlarmManager` only retains *one* alarm of a `PendingIntent` definition at a time. Setting an alarm will cause any previously scheduled alarm with the same `PendingIntent` to be canceled. `Intent` equality is defined in the [`filterEquals()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) method.